# Performance query PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

```
# table tbl_a
   ID
   Name
> tbl_a: 10000 record
CREATE INDEX ID on tbl_a USING btree (ID COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
```

---

```
# table tbl_b
   Branch
   ID
   name
> tbl_b: 1000 record
CREATE INDEX ID on tbl_b USING btree (ID COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
```

My function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_func()
RETURNS SETOF  AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  _r record;
BEGIN
 CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table AS
 SELECT branch, ID, Name from tbl_b where 1 = 0;
 FOR _r IN SELECT branch, ID, Name from tbl_b order by name
 LOOP
    INSERT INTO tmp_table 
    SELECT _r.branch, ID, Name FROM tbl_a  where ID = _r.ID and Name = _r.Name;
 END LOOP;
 //do something with tmp_table 
END
```

function performance slow in

> For ... Loop

Do you have any advice for performance improvements?
Please help me!

Comment: Never use for loops in plpgsql if you care about performance

Comment: Are you sure that this FOR LOOP is a problem. I create tables with 25000 records in tbl_a, and 1000 in tbl_b and used the functions. It is done in 33 ms in average.
And second thing what is relation between tbl_a, tbl_b? 1:1, 1:N, N:1. And why there is no unique ID on any of them?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `join` in your `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_table (id, name)
    SELECT a.ID, a.Name
    FROM tbl_a a JOIN
         tbl_b b
         ON a.id = b.id AND a.name b.Name;
```

Or perhaps:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_table (id, name)
    SELECT a.ID, a.Name
    FROM tbl_a a 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT b.ID, b.Name
    FROM tbl_b b;
```

Note that this will return duplicates, but that might be desirable.

Comment: The WHERE condition in the first option seems a bit odd.